# Can I use placeholders in an @Value annotated Resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to build a Spring Batch job, where the user gives the path to a directory as the input. In this directory is a csv-file and the name of this file is always different. I am defining my `ItemReader` with this Java Config:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<MyObject> itemReader(
        @Value("file:#{jobParameters['directory']}/*.csv") final Resource resource,
        final DefaultLineMapper<MyObject> lineMapper) {
    final FlatFileItemReader<MyObject> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    reader.setResource(resource);
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);

    return reader;
}
```

When I run the job I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): URL [file:C:/path/to/directory/*.csv]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144)
    ... 26 more
```

Obviously it is not possible to use an asterisk as a placeholder at this place. Is there any other way to get the path of the csv file dynamically?

Comment: The `FlatFileItemReader` needs an actual file not a directory or wildcard. The exception is also thrown by the `FlatFileItemReader`. Put some logic in there to get the name of the file from the given directory.

Comment: What do you mean by 'in there'?

Comment: In your `@Bean` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure about the directory and there is only one CSV file always, then you can go for create `File` object for the directory and get the first item from `listFiles()`, then create the Resource object, as shown below:

```
public FlatFileItemReader<MyObject> itemReader(
        @Value("file:#{jobParameters['directory']}") final String resourceDir,
        final DefaultLineMapper<MyObject> lineMapper) {

        File[] files=new File(resourceDir).listFiles(); // you can try giving FileNameFilter for .csv
        File csvFile=files[0]; // do null check and isempty
        // create Resource
        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(csvFile);
    final FlatFileItemReader<MyObject> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    reader.setResource(resource);
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);

    return reader;
}
```

Or, if the `.csv` file name has any static prefix or suffix you can try with the existing code itself. Please check section **6.7.2 Wildcards in application context constructor resource paths** [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html). For example, suppose in your case the `.csv` file has a pattern `abc*.csv`:

```
 @Value("file:#{jobParameters['directory']}/abc*.csv")
```